# How to get value of failed JSON validator attribute?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have below `json` input, where I am purposefully not sending the "Name" attribute.

```
 {
     "IsActive": false,
     "Contracts": [
     {
         "Id": 1
         "IsActive": true,
         "Name": "DH0",
     },
     {
         "Id": 2
         "IsActive": true
     }
 }
```

NewtonSoft JSON validator successfully validated the empty value of `Name`!

> "Required properties are missing from object: Name. Path '', line 11, position 1."

But I would like to get the value of "Id" where `Name` attribute is missing.

How can we do it?

**Current code**  (Updated code as per Robin Windey comment)

```
    string schemaJson = File.ReadAllText("schema/qmcrmdataschema.json");
    string inputJson = File.ReadAllText("schema/sample.json");

    JSchemaReaderSettings settings = new JSchemaReaderSettings
    {
        Validators = new List<JsonValidator> { new MyValidator() }
    };        

    JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson, settings );
    JObject user = JObject.Parse(inputJson);

    IList<ValidationError> messages;
    bool valid = user.IsValid(schema, out messages);

  Console.WriteLine(messages[0].Message);
```

Custom Validator

```
    public class MyValidator : JsonValidator
     {
      public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
      {
       
      }

      public override bool CanValidate(JSchema schema)
      {           
          return (schema.Format == "something");
      }
}
```

BUT custom code is not get hit by debugger!

What I am missing?

Comment: Did not test it but Custom JSON validators could be a good starting point for this? https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CustomJsonValidators.htm

Comment: Thanks @RobinWindey , but custom code is not getting hit.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you share your code? Usually you'll have to use JSchemaReaderSettings with a Validators collection containing an instance of your validator. Then use these settings to call JSchema.Parse. Also see the example on the bottom of the page i posted

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

`MyValidator.cs`

```cs
internal class MyValidator : JsonValidator
{
    private int _counter;

    public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validate");
        context.RaiseError($"MyCustomError {_counter++}");
    }

    public override bool CanValidate(JSchema schema)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine("CanValidate");
        return true;
    }
}
```

`schema.json`

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "IsActive": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "Contracts": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "IsActive": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "Name": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "Id",
              "IsActive",
              "Name"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "IsActive": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "Id",
              "IsActive"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "IsActive",
      "Contracts",
      "Name"
    ]
  }
```

`input.json`

```json
{
    "IsActive": false,
    "Contracts": [
      {
          "Id": 1,
          "IsActive": true,
          "Name": "DH0"
      },
      {
          "Id": 2,
          "IsActive": true
      }
    ]
}
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var schemaJson = File.ReadAllText("schema.json");
        var inputJson = File.ReadAllText("input.json");

        var settings = new JSchemaReaderSettings
        {
            Validators = new List<JsonValidator> { new MyValidator() }
        };   

        var schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson, settings);
        var user = JObject.Parse(inputJson);

        bool valid = user.IsValid(schema, out IList<ValidationError> errors);

        if (!valid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found errors:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors.Select(e => e.Message)));
        }
    }
```

Then, when running `dotnet run` it gave me the following console output:

```
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
CanValidate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Validate
Found errors:
MyCustomError 0
MyCustomError 1
MyCustomError 2
MyCustomError 3
MyCustomError 4
MyCustomError 5
MyCustomError 6
MyCustomError 7
MyCustomError 8
MyCustomError 9
Required properties are missing from object: Name.
```

You can see in the last line that the default validiation currently takes place, even though we have just defined our own `JsonValidator` inside the `Validators` collection of the `JSchemaReaderSettings` class. I did not yet manage to disable this behaviour but I think this should be a good starting point.

**Btw:** you had an syntax error in your `input.json`. Closing brackets of the `Contracts` array and comma after the `Id` properties are missing.

Comment: where it is showing Id:2 in your output?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?